# How to prevent label overlapping? How to write text at a point relative to plotLines?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, label

I have a tornado chart in which looks like this.[image]

The overlap of labels occurs because they have same value in the series. I want the first label to be right aligned and second label to be left aligned so that both the labels will be visible.

Apart from this, I also have a vertical line chart whose labels need to be left aligned to the line and clearly visible outside the bar column.

JSFiddle link of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/z2jyz7Ln/

The chart has a threshold 29.5 and the series is as follows:

```
series: [
        {type:'line',color:'black',zIndex:505,
         data:[[-0.25,29.5],[3.25,29.5]],
         marker:{
             enabled: false
         }
        },
        {
        threshold: 29.5,
        name: 'Low',
        grouping: false,
        type: 'bar',
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 12.15,
        }, {
            x: 1,
            y: 15.45,
        }, {
            x: 2,
            y: 29.5,
        }, {
            x: 3,
            y: 12.15,
        }],
        labels: [10, 5, 1, 2]
    }, {
        threshold: 29.5,
        name: 'High',
        grouping: false,
        type: 'bar',
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 46.86,
        }, {
            x: 1,
            y: 42.28,
        }, {
            x: 2,
            y: 29.5,
        }, {
            x: 3,
            y: 46.86,
        }],
        labels: [30, 10, 3, 4]
    }]
```

I need to make the changes pointed out in the image. Basically, I need to use different dataLabel alignments within same series. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can control position for each of dataLabels using point.dataLabel.x/y values: http://jsfiddle.net/z2jyz7Ln/1/

Code:

```
    data: [
        [-0.25, 29.5], 
        {
            x:3.25, 
            y:29.5,
            dataLabels: {
                y: 20,
                x: -20
            }
        }
    ],
```

Unfortunately you need to detect dataLabels collision on your own, Highcharts doesn't provide  such method.